# Responses missing in Google Forms under the 'Checkbox - Other' question

Tags: google-drive, google-forms

I have a Google Form with a checkbox question and I can see from the responses summary that two respondents have ticked 'Other'.

But, I can't see what they have typed, even in the responses spreadsheet.

Where can I see what they have entered?

Comment: I didn't test it because I didn't want to skew the results, but it looks like you are right.  It just appears as a comma-separated value, without `Other` and if it is blank, it doesn't even put in the comma separator.

Comment: @Jayen please have a look at an updated/enhanced answer on how the "_other_" field works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't, because Forms doesn't require a user to enter a value for Other, so your respondents most likely didn't enter one.

NB    I just submitted a response that doesn't have a value, and a second response that does.   I believe you will see two responses, and will be able to see the "this is an Other value" text for the second one.

I cannot see any way to make Forms insist that text is entered in the other text-box.

Comment: Please have a look at a recent [answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92763/117311) of mine.