# How do Google Forms handle the "Other" field in Multiple choice/Checkboxes/Drop-down questions?

Tags: google-forms

We use the "Other" option on our multiple choice questions but get inconsistent results recorded for the field on both the form "*Responses*" tab and the connected spreadsheet as well.

There seems to be an accepted [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/65504/117311) ("*...I cannot see **any way** to make Forms insist that text is entered in the other text-box.*") and one [more](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/66288/117311) ("*...**usually** don't show all the "other" responses as they are...*") on the subject.

But how exactly Google Forms handle the field and what can one expect on the "*Responses*" tab and the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as "*...**I cannot see any way** to make Forms insist that text is entered in the other text-box.*". There is a way to make Forms insist that text is entered in the other text-box.
**Mark the question as "*Required*"**.
As far as "*...**usually** don't show all the "other" responses as they are...*".
Google forms **always** handle Multiple choice/Checkboxes/Drop-down questions the same way.

To categorize, elaborate and clarify on the form reactions.

### Not required questions:

- The form does **not "care"** whether some input in the "*Other*" field exists or not.
- The form **will record** the "*Other*" field, only if there is **input** in it.
- The form **will not record** an answer when the "*Other*" field is selected but left **blank**.

  - The form **will not record** an answer not even if some **blank spaces** are entered, when the "*Other*" field is selected.

### Required questions:

- The form will **force** an answer to the question.
- The form **will accept/record** the "*Other*" field, only if there is **input** in it.
- The form **will not accept** (let alone record) the answer when the "*Other*" field is **selected** but left **blank**.

  - The form **will not accept** (let alone record) the answer not even if some **blank spaces** are entered, when the "*Other*" field is selected.

---

#### Further explanation

An easy way to understand how a Google Form works, is to **think** of the "*Other*" field existing in both the Multiple choice and Checkboxes as the option "*choose*" in **Drop-down lists**.

[image: drop-down]

The **added extra that comes with Multiple choice and Checkboxes** is that a submitter is allowed/forced to **provide one's own input** as an answer. So when one selects "*Other*" but provides no input -or just blank spaces- there is nothing for the form to record (as if it was never selected).

**Blank spaces entered**
[image: blank spaces]

__

You can also have a visual understanding by these screenshots of the "*SUMMARY*" tab:

**Old Forms**:
[image: old forms summary]

**New Forms**:
[image: new forms summary]

When a question is **not marked as "*Required*"**, you notice that although there are three responses submitted, there are only two answers recorded for the specific question and just one of those answers recorded for the "*Other*" field. That is because despite the fact that two people may have selected the "*other*" option, just one of them also provided some input for the field. Input you can see recorded under the "*INDIVIDUAL*" tab as well as the connected spreadsheet.
You can further verify the results by checking the "*INDIVIDUAL*" tab for each responder.

Keep in mind that submissions (as "entities") are stored within the form. **Spreadsheets only display the submissions** after a respond is submitted and only if they are already connected to the individual form. (That is exactly the reason why when even if you [delete a submission from the spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/91359/117311), you still have to delete it from within the form.)

Therefore, if an answer is not recorded by the form (no selection/selection carrying no input/blank spaces), even though you have the submission, there is no data to display for the specific answer in the spreadsheet, resulting the corresponding cell to be blank.